# How to save a value in a ReactJS page and use it in other pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, node-modules

Let me start by giving you a heads-up of me being a total noob in ReactJS.

I have this back-end code for the login page written in nodejs:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const { username, pass } = req.body;
    sqlLoginuser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?"
    db.query(sqlLoginuser, [username], (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        if (results.length === 0) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Username or password is incorrect" });
        }

        const user = results[0];

        bcrypt.compare(pass, user.pass, (error, result) => {
            if (error) throw error;

            if (!result) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Username or password is incorrect" });
            }

            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1h" });

            res.status(200).json({
                token,
                isAdmin: user.is_admin,
                message: "User logged in successfully",
            });
        });
    }
    );
});
```

I want to save the value of isAdmin sent by the backend from the database after a user is logged in in this Login page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import AuthContext from "./AuthContext";

const Login = () => {

    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [pass, setPass] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/login", {
                username,
                pass
            });
                toast.success("Te-ai logat cu succes")
                localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
                setIsAdmin(response.data.isAdmin);
                console.log(response.data.isAdmin);
                navigate("/ip");
                setTimeout(() => { window.location.reload() }, 2000);
        } catch (error) {
                toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                // toast.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAdmin, setIsAdmin }}>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "150px" }}>
                <form style={{
                    margin: "auto",
                    padding: "15px",
                    maxWidth: "400px",
                    alignContent: "center"
                }}
                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="username"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            value={pass}
                            onChange={(event) => setPass(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value={"Login"} />
                    <Link to="/register">
                        <input type="button" value="Fa-ti cont" />
                    </Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        </AuthContext.Provider>


    );
};

export default Login;
```

So that I can later use it's value in other pages, let's say for example in this page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './home.css';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';
import AuthContext from './AuthContext';


const IP = () => {

    const isAdmin = useContext(AuthContext);
    console.log("isAdmin:", isAdmin);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(0);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(1);

    const itemsPerPage = 10;

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        // Make a request to the backend to extract the information and store it in a text file
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/extract-ip")
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw new Error("Failed to extract data!");
                }
                const data = response.data;
                const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.download = 'ip.txt';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    };
    // code for fetching the users from the node.js backend to bring them to the frontend

    const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/ip?page=${currentPage}`);
        setData(response.data.data);
        setTotalPages(response.data.totalPages);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    });

    const deleteIp = (id) => {
        if (
            window.confirm("Stergeti intrarea?")
        ) {
            axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/delete-ip/${id}`)
            toast.success("Intrare eliminata cu succes!")
            setTimeout(() => loadData(), 500);
        }
    }

    const handlePageClick = (pageNumber) => {
        setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>

            <Link to="/addIp">
                <button className="btn btn-ip">Add IP</button>
            </Link>

            <table className='styled-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>No.</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>IP address</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Added on</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Added by</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((item, index) => {
                        const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
                        const rowNumber = startIndex + index + 1;
                        return (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <th scope="row">{rowNumber}</th>
                                <td>{item.ip_address}</td>
                                <td>{item.creation_date.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "").replace(".000", "")}</td>
                                <td>{item.published_by}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {isAdmin === "1" ?
                                        <>
                                            <Link to={`/update-ip/${item.id}`}>
                                                <button className="btn btn-edit">Edit</button>
                                            </Link>
                                            <button className="btn btn-delete" onClick={() => deleteIp(item.id)}>Delete</button>
                                            <button className="btn btn-edit" disabled={isLoading} onClick={handleClick}>{isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Extract Data"}</button>
                                        </>
                                        :
                                        <>
                                            <Link to="/addIp">
                                                <button className="btn btn-ip">Add IP</button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </>
                                    }
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="pagination">
                <ReactPaginate
                    pageCount={totalPages}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    onPageChange={(data) => handlePageClick(data.selected + 1)}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    activeClassName={"active"}
                />
            </div>
            {/* <Link to="/">
                <button className="btn btn-ip">Back</button>
            </Link> */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default IP;
```

Edit:

I managed to get the value in the Login.jsx, but when I try to pass it to the IP.jsx page, it doesn't get updated. For example

When I login the output of:

```
console.log(isAdmin) is 1
```

But in the IP page the output is 0.

Why is that happening?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [context](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context), but you definitely need to understand how to use props and state before attempting that.

I suggest you go through all the ["Learn" sections](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/describing-the-ui) in the react documentation.